# Twitter Puppeteer - how to click elements

Tags: node.js, twitter, puppeteer

Hello I'm trying join twitter via puppeteer to twitter, sign up via gmail.
But I'm facing objects I see by inspect aren't visible source of page, and I don't understand.

Here is example of code:

```
async function twitter(browserID) {
  const browserData = await getProfileData(browserID);
  const port = browserData.automation.port;
  const wsEndpoint = browserData.automation.wsEndpoint;

  // temp
  // let port = "52654";
  // let wsEndpoint = "/devtools/browser/7e7701c5-64c1-4d32-be9a-6198c58d58ae";

  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: `ws://127.0.0.1:${port}${wsEndpoint}`,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
  });

  await page.goto('https://twitter.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
  await sleep(5000);
  await page.click('span[class^="nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-"]');
  await sleep(3000);
};
```

I've fixed issue:

```
  await page.goto('https://twitter.com');

  await sleep(3000);
  const frame = page.frames().find(f => f.url().startsWith('https://accounts.google.com/gsi/button'));
  const acceptBtn = await frame.$('#container > div > div.nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-bN97Pc-sM5MNb.oXtfBe-l4eHX > span.nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-BPrWId');
  await acceptBtn.click();
```

Comment: Sometimes class names are different every time you load the page. Try using a different type of selector. Copy that element's xpath or something, anything as long as it is consistent everytime you load the page.

Comment: yes I was testing, but noticed that if I look into object span[class^="nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-"] and I try search class in source code, I cant find it.. and I read to use twitter u need load javascript. So I really dunno what is wrong

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than an edit to the post. Thanks.